# Perl Read every line of a text file search for a content and if not found replace it with new value

Tags: perl

I want to write a Perl script to search for a line in a file. If the line is found the user can exit, and if not he has to replace the line with the value given.

Below is the code. Everything is working fine, but the code is not replacing the content in the file.

Can you please correct where I am going wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Config;
use Socket;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use IO::Socket::INET;
use FileHandle;

my $filepath = "D\:\\Perl Docs and installers\\Platform\.log";

&DRbackupconfiguration( $filepath, "DRCOPY", "1000" );

sub DRbackupconfiguration {
    my ( $filepath, $parameter, $value ) = @_;

    my $status = "True";

    open my $info, $filepath or die "Could not open $filepath: $!";

    foreach ( my $line = <$info> ) {

        if ( $line =~ /$parameter/ ) {

            if ( $line ne $parameter . "/=" . $value ) {

                print "The initial parameter is $parameter \n";
                print "The initial value is $value \n";

                $line = $parameter . "=" . $value;

                open( FH, $filepath ) || die("-E- Unable to open \n");
                print( FH $line );

                print "The parameter is $parameter \n";
                print "the line is $line \n";
                close $info;

                print "$value \n";
                print "Value Changed \n";
            }
            else {
                print "Configuration already exists. Hence no changes made. /n";
            }
        }
        else {
            print "Parameter does not exist in the file \n";
            my $status = "False";
        }
    }
    close FH;
}
```

Comment: Where do you guys get the idea to call Perl subroutines with `&`? That must be some ancient tutorial, as it hasn't been correct since the summer of 2002 when Perl v5.8 came out

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using **sed** command for global search and replace? Just one line of shell command can change matched texts globally in the file.

```
sed -i "s/text_to_change/text_to_put/g" filename
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I ca tell, you want to check whether a value for the given parameter already exists  in the file, and add it if not

The main problem is that you are testing *every line* of the input file, and declaring that the parameter doesn't exist anywhere in the file each time it isn't found in one of the lines

You should read through the *whole file* and test whether the parameter exists anywhere. If not then you need to rewrite the whole file with the new line added

This should be close to what you need

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $filepath = 'D:\Perl Docs and installers\Platform.log';

dr_backup_configuration( $filepath, 'DRCOPY', 1000 );

sub dr_backup_configuration {

    my ( $filepath, $parameter, $value ) = @_;

    my @log = do {
        open my $fh, $filepath or die qq{Unable to open "$filepath" for input: $!};
        <$fh>;
    };
    chomp @log;

    my $found = grep { $_ =~ /^$parameter=(.+)/ } @log;

    if ( $found ) {
        warn qq{Parameter "$parameter" already exists with value "$1". No changes made.\n};
    }
    else {

        print qq{The initial parameter is "$parameter"\n};
        print qq{The initial value is "$value"\n};

        my $newline = "$parameter=$value";

        open my $fh, '>', $filepath or die qq{Unable to open "$filepath" for output: $!};
        print $fh "$_\n" for @log, $newline;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your suggestions. Below is the code snippet that served my purpose;

```
             #!/usr/bin/perl

            use strict;
            use warnings;
            use Config;
            use Socket;
            use POSIX qw(strftime);
            use IO::Socket::INET;

            my $filepath = 'D:\Perl Docs and installers\test.log';
            my $parameter="";
            my $value="";

            dr_backup_configuration( $filepath, 'DRCOPY', '20');

            sub dr_backup_configuration 
            {

                my ( $filepath, $parameter, $value ) = @_;    
                open my $file, $filepath or die "Could not open file: $!";
                my @arrayTemp;
                my $i=0;   
                while (my $line=<$file>)
                {
                    if ($line=~/$parameter.*=/)
                    {
                        print "The parameter is $parameter \n";
                        my $expectedline="$parameter"."="."$value";         
                        $line =~s/^\s+|s+$//g;
                        $expectedline =~s/^\s+|s+$//g;
                        chomp($line);
                        chomp($expectedline);
                        if ($line eq $expectedline)
                        {
                            print "Paramter passed and the parameter available in the file is same \n";
                            last;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        print "Paramter passed and the parameter available in the file are not same. Hence replacing the value \n";
                        $line = "$expectedline\n" ;
                        }
                    }        
                      $arrayTemp[$i]=$line;   
                      $i++;        
                      print "$line \n";                
                }
                open(my $fileWrite, "> $filepath") or die "$filepath";
                print $fileWrite @arrayTemp;
                close $fileWrite;
                close $file;              
             }
```